# Problema com JPGEncoder e FileReference

Tags: actionscript-3

Estou tentando salvar o conteúdo de um MovieClip em uma imagem, porém ao tentar salvar a imagem acontece o seguinte erro:

[imagem com espaço branco http://www.panrotas.com.br/v2/test.jpg](http://www.panrotas.com.br/v2/test.jpg)

Aparece um espaço branco em todas as imagens que salvo utilizando o `FileReference` em conjunto com o `JPGEncoder`.

Acredito que o problema esteja relacionado ao `JPGEncoder`, embora não tenha certeza disso.

Segue a função que utilizo para salvar as imagens:

```
private function fl_Salvar(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            try
            {
                var src:BitmapData = new BitmapData(imageViewer.width,imageViewer.height);


                var mtx:Matrix = DisplayUtils.fitIntoRect(imageViewer.mcImage.getChildAt(0),rect,true,Alignment.MIDDLE,false);

                src.draw(imageViewer,mtx,null,null,null,true);

                var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
                var imgStream:ByteArray = null; 
                imgStream = jpgEncoder.encode(src);

                var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
                file.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler );
                file.save( imgStream, "TESTE.jpg");
            }
            catch (ioe:IllegalOperationError)
            {
                trace("Operação Ilegal.");
            }
            catch (ae:ArgumentError)
            {
                trace("Argumento Inválido.");
            }
            catch (me:MemoryError)
            {
                trace("Memória Insuficiente.");
            }
            catch (error:Error)
            {
                trace("Erro ao tentar salvar imagem : "
                              + " . Erro : " + error);
            }
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler( event:IOErrorEvent ):void
        {
            trace("Handler de erro I/O: " + event);
        }
```

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe o que está causando essa área em branco nas imagens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, percebi que você está utilizando [esta biblioteca](http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/fit-a-displayobject-into-a-rectangle), correto?

O que eu entendi é que ela faz o recorte de um objeto `DisplayObject`, alterando suas propriedades e retornando a `Matrix` deste recorte. Fiz alguns testes aqui e tentei emular o seu erro. O que eu cheguei mais próximo foi onde eu alterei o tamanho do Retângulo de Dimensão para um número **MENOR** que o meu `DisplayObject`...

Segue abaixo o código com **erro**, supondo que meu `MovieClip` (*DisplayObject*) tenha o tamanho de 300x300px:

```js
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
var matrix:Matrix = DisplayUtils.fitIntoRect(movieclip, rect, true, Alignment.MIDDLE, false);
var bitData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(movieclip.width, movieclip.height);
bitData.draw(movieclip, matrix);
```

Logicamente a classe DisplayUtils está diminuindo o tamanho do movieclip (para 100x100), porém mantendo a proporção do objeto final, que é de 300x300px.

Quando você for salvar esta imagem, ela será salva com o tamanho de 300x300px, porém com espaços em branco tanto na vertical como na horizontal.

Agora, tente realizar esta operação, colocando o valor do retângulo exatamente igual ao tamanho original do seu MovieClip, acredito que será salvo corretamente!

Fiz este código abaixo, apenas para testes, repare que ao aumentar e diminuir o tamanho do seu Retângulo, a sua imagem final ficará ou com espaços em branco ou com partes faltando, porém quando o tamanho do retângulo for o mesmo que do movieclip, ele funcionará normalmente.

```js
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
var matrix:Matrix = DisplayUtils.fitIntoRect(imagem_movieclip, rect, true, Alignment.MIDDLE, false);

function mcToImage(mc:MovieClip):void {

    var bitData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height);
    bitData.draw(mc, matrix);

    var jpge:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);

    var ba:ByteArray = jpge.encode(bitData);

    var fileref:FileReference = new FileReference();
    fileref.save(ba, "teste.jpg");

}

mcToImage(imagem_movieclip);
```